# Cómo es la manera correcta de hacer for while en php?

Tags: php, bucle-for

Estoy necesitando realizar un `do while` o `for` o una manera correcta para poder repetir contenido

```
<?php 
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $database_conexion);
$query_DatosCategorias = sprintf("SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE estado>0");
$DatosCategorias= mysqli_query($conexion, $query_DatosCategorias) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_DatosCategorias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosCategorias);
$totalRows_DatosCategorias = mysqli_num_rows($DatosCategorias);

$total = $totalRows_DatosCategorias;
$limite = 8;
$listas = null;
$inicio = 1;
$k = null;
$listas = $total/$limite;
$cantidadListas = ceil($listas);
?>
<footer class="site-footer footer-light"
  style="background-image: url(<?php echo $urlWeb;?>/img/footer-bg-alt.png);">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!-- categorias-->
        <section class="widget widget-links">
          <h3 class="widget-title">Categorias</h3>
          <div class="row">
<?php
for ($i=$inicio; $i <=$cantidadListas; $i++) { 
  echo "<div class='col-md-6'>";
  for ($j=1; $j <=$limite && $k<$total; $j++) { 
    $k = $k+1;
    //acá necesito hacer un bucle for o while pero no me da resultado
    echo "<ul>";
    echo '<li>'.$row_DatosCategorias['id'].'</li>';
    echo "</ul>";
  }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar del `for`, pon un `while` para recorrer el resultado. He sacado la etiqueta `ul` fuera porque he supuesto que los resultados son los items de la lista.
Modificado para que salgan varias listas.

```
$i=0;
while ($row_DatosCategorias = mysql_fetch_assoc($DatosCategorias)) {
  $i++;
  if ($i==1) {echo "<ul>";} // primera lista
  echo '<li>'.$row_DatosCategorias['id'].'</li>';
  if ($i % $limite == 0 || $i == $total) { 
    echo "</ul>"; // cerrar lista
    // Si quedan más elementos abrir otra
    if ($i < $total) {echo "<ul>";}
  }
}
```

Comment: si a eso lo he implementado como tu lo marcastes pero aun sigo viendo cual puede ser una solución adecuada por que el tema es que quiero mostrar 10 resultados y cada 10 genere el col-md-6 es para el footer de una tienda lo tengo echo enci con los for pero al momento de poner un bucle mysql ya no me reconoce el for por decirlo gracias igualmente por tu aporte :)

Comment: Ah, ya veo lo que quieres

Comment: @matias si tú quieres mostrar un cierto contenido cada 10 elementos, sería más elegante hacer algo así: `$i=0; foreach ($arr as $row){$i++; if ($i % 10 == 0) {//Hay 10, mostrar contenido que deseas cada 10 elementos}  //mostrar contenido común }` ... lo demás sobra, si es que entendí bien lo que quieres.

Comment: @A.Cedano a dale voy a ver como implemento sus ayudas si lo que quiero hacer es algo complejo pero gran mayoría lo tengo.  me faltaba el final ahora ire viendo como implementarlo de forma correcta :)